# Fastest way to append a character N times

Tags: javascript

I was doing a question on Javascript where I had to append dashes N times.
Naturally I ran a for loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<num; i++)
{
newStr+="-";
}
```

But then I realise that I could cut the runtime in half if I append two dashes in one loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<num/2; i++)
{
newStr+="--"
}
if (num%2==1)
{
newStr+=1;
}
```

So if I append three dashes in one loop I could cut in in 1/3 of the time taken?

But appending too much will somehow make it back to square one.

What is the fastest/most optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `String.prototype.repeat`:

```
newStr += '-'.repeat(num)
```

```js
let newStr = 'foo';
const num = 5;
newStr += '-'.repeat(num)
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: I did not know this one. I was thinking `Array(num).fill("-").join("")` before I saw yours

Comment: Or padEnd(n,"-")

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to add `num` dashes to the existing string, no matter how long the original string is, so I don't think `padEnd` would do the job

Comment: `str.padEnd(str.length+num,"-")` would